# AMD card fails to start when displayport plugged in

Tags: displayport, amd-graphics-card

I've been encountering this issue for a while now and it has finally fried enough nerves that I'd find some support for it. Googling around has revealed little.

I have an AMD Radeon HD 5900 with 2 displays:

- a DVI at 16:10 2K resolution
- a DisplayPort 16:9 2K resolution.

The issue I am experiencing is when I turn the PC on with both adapters plugged in the monitors fail to turn on. If I connect the the PC with TeamViewer I experience 800x600 resolution so I assume the PC is failing to recognise my GPU.

However if I start my PC with the DisplayPort unplugged, wait for the DVI monitor to turn on then plug the DisplayPort in everything works fine.

Restarting the PC without unplugging the DisplayPort works fine as well. But shutting it down and then immediately turning it back on persists with the original problem.

I must plug the DisplayPort out from my GPU, it doesn't work if I unplug it from my monitor.

The current drivers are: 14.10.1006-140417a-171099C

Answer (score 0):

My guess is, that your RADEON card is NOT a real dual-screen adapter. It just gives you the choice to use DVI or DisplayPort. That could be the reason for the different results you get from "pulling the plugs". - If you have any other display connections on your PC (like VGA, onboard etc.), try using that one for monitor_2 and then use your RADEON card for monitor_1 (doesn't matter if you use DVI or DisplayPort, just not both).